# MS Edge - hosts file bypassing

Tags: windows, networking, microsoft-edge, reverse-engineer

As its seems that Microsoft have hardcoded Bing domains somewere - [MS Edge bypassing hosts file Bing entries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=u1kGMCfb2xw#t=1166) - have anyone an idea how to:

- Check where is it hardcoded and possibly find what else is hardcoded?
- Restore host file functionality somehow without custom DNS server?

Comment: if it is hardcoded, there are almost no options other than to get the code, edit it, and recompile the program from it. The only other alternatives involve disassambly and binary patching, both of which are topics way beyond the scope of SU. This likely isn't somthing you can fix.

Comment: @FrankThomas Maybe hardcoded is a wrong word - I count on register entry or something...

Comment: Curious as to why you'd want to bother?

Comment: @Linef4ult HTTPS forcing and king of search anonymization.